# React : How to trigger a function on the "onClick" event, but on a component?

Tags: reactjs

I try to trigger the `handleClick` function when i click on my `Trash` component, but it doesn't work because `Trash` is not a DOM object. How can i trigger my function when i click on this component ?

```
const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('OK');
  }

  return (
    <div className="comment">
      {trash && <Trash comment={comment} onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Whatever the "Trash" component is needs to have something in it that's clickable and calls the handler.

Comment: Can you share the `Trash` component? Without that code, we can't understand why `handleClick` isn't being called.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your Trash component to accept an `onClick` prop, and to pass it down to the returned JSX. Something like:

```
const Trash = (props) => {
  // ...
  return (
    // whatever the top level element here is,
    // add the onclick prop to it
    <div onClick={props.onClick}>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};
```